# Multiple select or distinct

Tags: sql

I am new to sql so looking for a little help - got the first part down however I am having issues with the second part.

I got the three tables tied together.  First I needed to tie tblPatient.ID = tblPatientVisit.PatientID together to eliminate dups which works

Now I need to take those results and eliminate dups in the MRN but my query is only returning one result which is WRONG - LOL

Query

```
select 
      tblPatient.id, 
      tblPatient.firstname, 
      tblPatient.lastname, 
      tblPatient.dob, 
      tblPatient.mrn, 
      tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder.SmokeStatus, 
      tblPatientVisit.VisitNo 
   from
      tblPatient, 
      tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder, 
      tblPatientVisit
   Where 
      tblPatient.ID = tblPatientVisit.PatientID 
      and tblPatientVisit.ID = tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder.VisitID
      and tblPatient.ID in(
         Select Distinct 
            tblPatient.mrn
         From 
            tblPatient
         where
            isdate(DOB) = 1 
            and Convert(date,DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
            and tblPatientVisit.PatientType = 'I')
```

Actual Results:

```
ID | firstName  | LastName  | DOB        | MRN     | SmokeStatus  | VisitNO
12 | Test Guy   | Today     | 12/12/1023 | 0015396 | Never Smoker | 0013957431
```

Desired Results:

```
90 | BOB        | BUILDER   | 02/24/1974 | 0015476 | Former Smoker | 0015476001
77 | DORA       | EXPLORER  | 06/04/1929 | 0015463 | Never Smoker  | 0015463001
76 | MELODY     | VALENTINE | 09/17/1954 | 0015461 | Current       | 0015461001
32 | STRAWBERRY | SHORTCAKE | 07/06/1945 | 0015415 | Current       | 0015415001
32 | STRAWBERRY | SHORTCAKE | 07/06/1945 | 0015415 | Never Smoker  | 0015415001
32 | STRAWBERRY | SHORTCAKE | 07/06/1945 | 0015415 | Former Smoker | 0015415001
12 | Test Guy   | Today     | 12/12/1023 | 0015345 | Never Smoker  | 0013957431
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I go down to the next level and get all the rows with one unique MRN.  From the data above I should have 5 in my list.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess -- The only thing that looks odd (but maybe it's OK) is that you're comparing `patient.ID` from your parent query to `patient.mrn` in the subquery.

Beyond that -- things to check:

(1)
Do you get all your patients with the inner query?

```
Select Distinct 
   tblPatient.mrn
From 
   tblPatient
where
   isdate(DOB) = 1 
   and Convert(date,DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
   and tblPatientVisit.PatientType = 'I'
```

(2)
What is your patient type for the missing records?  (Your filtering it to `tblPatientVisit.PatientType = 'I'` -- do the missing records have that patient type as well?)

Comment: Questions to the OP should be posted as comments and not as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to invert the logic here.  As in,

```
Select Distinct 
   patients.mrn1
From (select 
         tblPatient.id as id1, 
         tblPatient.firstname as firstname1, 
         tblPatient.lastname as lastname1, 
         tblPatient.dob as DOB1, 
         tblPatient.mrn as mrn1, 
         tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder.SmokeStatus as SmokeStatus1, 
         tblPatientVisit.VisitNo as VisitNo1, 
         tblPatientVisit.PatientType as PatientType1,
      from
         tblPatient, 
         tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder, 
         tblPatientVisit
      Where 
         tblPatient.ID = tblPatientVisit.PatientID 
         and tblPatientVisit.ID = tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder.VisitID
   ) as patients
where
   isdate(patients.DOB1) = 1 
   and Convert(date,patients.DOB1) <'12/10/2000' 
   and patients.PatientType1 = 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned it up a bit and I think they were right. MRN wont match patient id, at least not from your example data. You should not need an inner query. This query should give you what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      p.id, 
      p.firstname, 
      p.lastname, 
      p.dob, 
      p.mrn, 
      s.SmokeStatus, 
      v.VisitNo 
 FROM
      tblPatient p 
      JOIN tblPatientVisit v ON p.id = v.patientId
      JOIN tblPatientSmokingScreenOrder s ON v.id = s.visitId  
 WHERE 
      isdate(p.DOB) = 1 
      AND CONVERT(date,p.DOB) <'12/10/2000' 
      AND v.PatientType = 'I'
```

Comment: this is so close but still has dups